# Call to Web API from Xamarin Android not returning results

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.ios, xamarin, httpclient

Hi I have created a solution with 3 projects in it. My solution has  a Windows console app, a Xamarin Android project and a portable class library (PCL). I have referenced my PCL in both the Console and Android app. My PCL has my Models and ViewModels and i am calling a Web API from the viewModels. Here is a sample viewModel

```
 public class RoutineViewModel
  {
     public async Task<IEnumerable<Routine>> GetRoutines()
      {
       //Lets Get List from Routines Web API
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            var json = await client.GetStringAsync(BroadCastApiUrls.Routines);
            var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Routine>>(json);

            if (results.Any())
                return results;
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Some logging code here

            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

I am making via an instance of this RoutineViewModel in a Method call from a button click handler, here is the code calling the GetRoutines Method

```
//In the Activity class 
  readonly RoutineViewModel routineViewModel = new RoutineViewModel();     

   private async Task<bool> LoadRoutines()
     {
         try
         {
            var routines = await routineViewModel.GetRoutines();
            if (routines != null)
            {
                routinesList = routines.ToList();
                listView.Adapter = new RoutinesListAdapter(this, routinesList);
            }
            else
            {
                var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                var alert = builder.Create();
                alert.SetTitle("No Results!");
                // alert.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable)
                alert.SetMessage("No Routines From API!");
                alert.DismissEvent += alert_DismissEvent;

                alert.Show();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Some logging and clean up code
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This call returns the expected results from my console app but the same method call on my android simulator returns no results. What am i missing here? its driving me nuts.

Edit

From the loadRoutines  click handler the call is

```
 bool isLoaded = await LoadRoutines();
```

Comment: show LoadRoutines call please

Comment: Edited the post.

The big issue is that the following part of code in LoadRoutines is returning null
'code'
 var routines = await routineViewModel.GetRoutines();
'code'
 when the same call in the console app gives results

Comment: Does your app have Internet permissions?  Have you tried stepping through the code to check for errors, exceptions, etc?

Comment: Yes i have stepped through the code.. it just gives the null result

Comment: Hi Jason , what do you mean by Internet permissions?

Comment: Your AndroidManifest file has a list of device features the app is allowed to access.  Be sure it is allowed to use the internet

Comment: @zimcoder in relation to connection comment, are you running the Android App in a VM and your Web API on a localhost?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably calling `Task<T>.Result` or `Task.Wait` further up the call stack, which will work on Console apps but fail in a GUI context. I explain this behavior in more detail [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

The best solution is to use `await` instead of `Result` or `Wait`. Note that this means you'll have to decide what your UI looks like while the routines are loading, and then *update* it with the results when the loading completes.

Comment: I Stephen, i did as you suggested and i still cant get it to work

Comment: Are you using `await` **all the way up**?